# Midi - how to get all notes for specific second(s)

Tags: python, midi

I am in the middle of a project and sadly don't know much about MIDI files. I am using [python library for MIDI](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) files.

The main question is how to get all notes (messages) for a specific time && track ( for example 1:20 to 1:21)

The other issue is: in some MIDI files, we have different tempo speeds. I can solve this issue by counting the time, and velocity, but I don't know how to convert these numbers to Second and apply different tempos.

Comment: See `sequencer.py` for how to handle time stamps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of that library (which seems to be currently unmaintained), you may use another one providing times in seconds out of the box for each event, for instance using [pretty-midi](https://github.com/craffel/pretty-midi) - [docs](http://craffel.github.io/pretty-midi/) (python 3):

```
import pretty_midi
midi_data = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI('example.mid')
print("duration:",midi_data.get_end_time())
print(f'{"note":>10} {"start":>10} {"end":>10}')
for instrument in midi_data.instruments:
    print("instrument:", instrument.program);
    for note in instrument.notes:
        print(f'{note.pitch:10} {note.start:10} {note.end:10}')
```

You can filter the note events by `note.start` and `note.end` times already computed in seconds.